# How to configure Raspberry pi 3 for RTC PCF8563

Tags: pi-3, debian, rtc

I am using RTC PCF8563 module with my raspberry pi 3.I tried to configure RTC clock by using command sudo hwclock -w,but every time restart i am getting old clock time of shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

See `/boot/overlays/README`.

Add the following line to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,param=pcf8563
```

Comment: I have made the change still i am getting same problem .